# Edit Quicktime file header - audio tracks assignment flags, Timecode track

Tags: python, audio, video, pyqt, quicktime

I use Python quite a bit and am looking for a way to edit a Quicktime file flags via Python / command line. I need to edit the audio tracks assignment flags, Left, Right, Left Surround, etc, also edit Timecode track, Pixel Aspect ratio, etc, quicktime atoms. I have been looking for some time of how this can be done programatically via python but can't find anyway, I don't wan't to re-encode the file, just change the flags. can PyQt do this?

Comment: No, Qt does not have any specific support for Quicktime.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/index.html), but it might look like what you need.

> pyglet: a cross-platform windowing and multimedia library for Python.
>
> Load images, sound, music and video in almost any format. pyglet can optionally use AVbin to play back audio formats such as MP3, OGG/Vorbis and WMA, and video formats such as DivX, MPEG-2, H.264, WMV and Xvid.

Take a look at the [pyglet documentation](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/) for more information.

Comment: Took a look and I don't think pyglet will do this sort of thing.

Comment: @speedyrazor Not sure what platform you are on, but there used to be a module for quicktime on mac but seems to be deprecated now.

Comment: I am on OSX, could you point me i the right direction please?

Comment: @speedyrazor Here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/carbon.html - However alot of the functions seems to be deprecated or/and removed in later versions of OSX.